# How to export mail messages from outlook express?

Tags: email, export, outlook-express

Every time I try to export mail from outlook express it comes up with an error saying "An error occurred while initializing MAPI."  I've never found a way around this problem but it occurs on every computer I have ever tried exporting from.  What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

crude but it works:

copy the OE store folder to another computer. now you can either import import into OE by picking the option **import mail from an OE store directory** or just change the store folder from the Maintenance tab to the backup folder.

now if you want to use these messages with Outlook, just import from OE.

and of course there is a detailed [MSKB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179637) article regarding te matter.

Comment: Where is the OE store folder?

Comment: Aha: http://www.z-a-recovery.com/outlook-express-dbx.htm